# How does Gensim implement subsampling in Word2Vec?

Tags: gensim, word2vec, subsampling

I am trying to reimplement wor2vec in pytorch. I implemented subsamping according to the [code](https://github.com/tmikolov/word2vec/blob/20c129af10659f7c50e86e3be406df663beff438/word2vec.c#L407) of the original paper. However, I am trying to understand how subsampling is implemented in Gensim. I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/word2vec.py), but I did not manage to grasp how it reconnects to the original paper.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key line is:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/e391f0c25599c751e127dde925e062c7132e4737/gensim/models/word2vec_inner.pyx#L543

```py
    if c.sample and word.sample_int < random_int32(&c.next_random):
        continue
```

If `c.sample` tests if frequent-word downsampling is enabled at all (any non-zero value).

The `word.sample_int` is a value, per vocabulary word, that was precalculated during the vocabulary-discovery phase. It's essentially the 0.0-to-1.0 probability that a word should be kept, but scaled to the range 0-to-(2^32-1).

Most words, that are never down-sampled, simply have the value (2^32-1) there - so no matter what random int was just generated, that random int is less than the threshold, and the word is retained.

The few most-frequent words have other scaled values there, and thus sometimes the random int generated is larger than their `sample_int`. Thus, that word is, in that one training-cycle, skipped via the `continue` to the next word in the sentence. (That one word doesn't get made part of `effective_words`, this one time.)

You can see the original assignment & precalculation of the `.sample_int` values, per unique vocabulary word, at and around:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/e391f0c25599c751e127dde925e062c7132e4737/gensim/models/word2vec.py#L1544

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation @gojomo